# CSS Background-Image strech height

Tags: css, height

I want my background-image to be always at the same height with the user's desktop screen. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, it is possible, how does the markup you use look like?

Answer (score 0):

This should be possible to do by setting the height of the image to a height of 100vh but this isn't supported in IE8 or lower.

Answer (score 0):

Try this on the body (or the container that has the background image):

```
body { 
  background-size: contain;
}
```